# Double centralizers in $\text{Hom}(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Exercise 3.20 in 'Advanced Calculus' by Loomis and Sternberg writes:

> If $S$ and $T$ are in $\text{Hom}(V)$, we say that $S$ *doubly commutes* with $T$ (and writes $S\text{ cc }T$) if $S$ commutes with every $A$ in $\text{Hom}(V)$ which commutes with $T$. Fix $T$, and set $\left\{ T \right\}''=\left\{S:S\text{ cc }T\right\}$. Show that $\left\{ T \right\}''$ is a commutative subalgebra of $\text{Hom}(V)$.

Here, $V$ is a (real) vector space and $\text{Hom}(V)$ is the algebra of linear maps from $V$ into $V$.

Paraphrasing a little bit, let us write $C(A)$ for the centralizer of $A$, a subset of $\text{Hom}(V)$. Then the exercise asks to show that $C(C(T))$ is a commutative subalgebra of $\text{Hom}(V)$.

What I figured is that $C(A)=C(<A>)$ where $<>$ denotes the subalgebra generated by $A$, and that $C(A)$ is always a subalgebra of $\text{Hom}(V)$. Also, $C(C(A))$ always contains $A$ as a subset, so we see that $C(C(T))$ contains the set of 'polynomials' in $T$, which is the subalgebra generated by $T$.

$$C(C(T))\supset\text{polynomials in }T$$

But I don't see why $C(C(T))$ must be a commutative subalgebra. Does $C(C(T))$ equal the set of polynomials in $T$? I have no idea how to proceed from here. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by hand.

Clearly, $0\in\{T\}''$ and $1\in\{T\}''$ (identity map).

If $S_1,S_2\in\{T\}''$ and $A$ commutes with $T$, then
\begin{align}
&(S_1-S_2)A=S_1A-S_2A=AS_1-AS_2=A(S_1-S_2),
\\
&(S_1S_2)A=S_1(S_2A)=S_1(AS_2)=(S_1A)S_2=(AS_1)S_2=A(S_1S_2)
\end{align}
therefore $\{T\}''$ is a subalgebra.

Now note that, since $S\in\{T\}''$ commutes with every linear map that commutes with $T$, in particular it commutes with $T$. So, by definition, $S$ commutes with every map in $\{T\}''$.